# wp theme fixed header overlaps content

Tags: css, header, fixed

Im working on the SimplePhoto WP Theme.

I did figure out how to fix the header by editing the STYLE.CSS, but now part of the content is underneath the header.

any sugestions?

This is the site i'm woring on: http://vivaarquitetura.com.br/wp/

Tks

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the "*This should be a centered paragraph*" lines are beneath the header, just increase the top padding of `#single_cont` like this:

```
#single_cont { padding: 130px 0 0;}
```